# How to send data in url without using web() in MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab

I have to send data using url in MATLAB. currently I am sending it like this

```
str=http://192.168.4.1?vno=AP09BN7886;
web(str);
```

In this it sends data('AP09BN7886') to IP(192.168.4.1) but it opens browser and also is not fast enough. Can you suggest me anyother way to send and also recieve data like this in matlab. I think I can probably use urlread() or urlwrite() but I don't understand how to use them.

Comment: have you tried UDP? http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/165759

Comment: Okay I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried sending like this but it didn't work. 
       
    `s='?vno=AP09BN7886'; `
    `u=udp('192.168.4.1', 80,'LocalPort', 80);`
    `fopen(u)`
    `fwrite(u, s);`
    `fclose(u)`

Comment: What exactly are you running on your server (192.168.4.1)? An HTTP server or something else? Your own program maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you prefix your statement with a `!` you can enter a bash command.  Can you use cURL for what you want?  For example `! curl --data "AP09BN7886" http://192.168.4.1`